# Discord Py - How can I add_role to user on_message?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to use regex to look at and accept literally ANY incoming message from a user and assign them a role. But ONLY if that user does not have a role already assigned to them. I don't get any errors when running the code, but it does not work.

Here is what I have:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    match = re.search(r'(.*?)', message.content)
    member = message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Creators")
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if role not in member.roles:
        if match and message.channel.id == target_channel:
            # add member to role
            # send message to to users
            await message.channel.send(
                f'Hi {message.author}, welcome to the server! Don\'t forget to choose your #roles'
            )
            await discord.Member.add_roles(member, role)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys, it turns out it was something very minor (and dumb on my part) that prevented it from working.

when comparing `message.channel.id`.id to `target_channel`, I forgot that the channel id object does not come in as a string, but target_channel was set up as a string, so it failed to see them as equal. Simply converting `message.channel.id` to string did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

```
await discord.Member.add_roles(member, role)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_role#discord.Member.add_roles

As you can see from the documentation the passed arguments is `*roles, reason=None, atomic=True`. `roles` is something you have to specify, `reason` and `atomic` are optional.

You tried passing `member` which is not a valid argument.

`discord.Member` is a class. You need to get an `instance` of that class. `ctx.author` is an instance of `discord.Member`.

So the final call should be:

```
await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: `*roles` is an argument list, which means that it should be passed as separate arguments, not a list.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I removed the false information.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `Member` object from `on_message`, you can use `member = message.author`.
Then simply do `member.add_roles(role)`.